# memset setting character pointers NULL/Garbage

Tags: c, sockets, memset

Below is one function of my C program. In the below function I'm passing 3 char pointers but I'm not at all using them in the function. However after the execution of memset() function the values of the strings are either becoming NULL or GARBAGE. Can anybody let me know why is this happening ?

Here is the complete code ....Please ignore bad coding style as its my test code :) .

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>


static void * process_request_client(void *arg);
void getClientInput(int sockfd, char ** ptr_ip_addr, char ** ptr_port_no, char ** ptr_page);
int split( char * str, char delim, char ***array, int *length );
int connect_web(char * ip_addr, char * port, char * page);
void process_webPage(int soc_client, int soc_web, char * page, char * host);
//##############

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
   /* variables section */
   pthread_t tid;
   int                listenfd, connfd;
   pid_t              childpid;
   socklen_t          clilen;
   struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;

   /* creating a socket */
   if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
     printf("\n%s: Error in socket", argv[0]);
     exit(0);
   }

   /* configuring server address structure */
   bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
   servaddr.sin_port        = htons(9876); 

   /* binding our socket to the service port */
   if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
     printf("\n%s: Error in bind", argv[0]); 
     exit(0);
   } 

   /* convert our socket to a listening socket */
   if (listen(listenfd, 5) < 0) {
     printf("\n%s: Error in listen", argv[0]); 
     exit(0);
   } 

   for ( ; ; ) {
     clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);

     /* accept a new connection and return a new socket descriptor to 
     handle this new client */
     if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cliaddr, &clilen)) < 0) {
       printf("\n%s: Error in accept", argv[0]); 
       exit(0);
     } 

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &process_request_client, (void *) connfd);   
  }
  return 0;
}


static void * process_request_client(void *soc_client) {
    char * ip_addr;
    char ** ptr_ip_addr;
    char * port_no;
    char ** ptr_port_no;
    char * page;
    char ** ptr_page;

    ptr_ip_addr = &ip_addr;
    ptr_port_no = &port_no;
    ptr_page = &page;

    int soc_web;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    getClientInput((int) soc_client,ptr_ip_addr,ptr_port_no,ptr_page);

    printf("ip_addr in process_request_client -> %s \n port in process_request_client-> %s \n page in process_request_client->%s\n",ip_addr,port_no,page);

    //create socket connection to web server
    soc_web = connect_web(ip_addr, port_no, page);

    printf("ip_addr in process_request_client -> %s \n port in process_request_client-> %s \n page in process_request_client->%s\n",ip_addr,port_no,page);

    //process webPage
    //process_webPage((int)soc_client, soc_web, page, ip_addr);

    printf("ip_addr in process_request_client -> %s \n port in process_request_client-> %s \n page in process_request_client->%s\n",ip_addr,port_no,page);

    close(soc_web);
    close((int) soc_client);
    return (NULL);
}

void getClientInput(int sockfd, char ** ptr_ip_addr, char ** ptr_port_no, char ** ptr_page){
    ssize_t n;
    char line[512];
    char **res;
    int rc, count = 0, k=0;
    /* read from socket */
    n = read(sockfd, (void *) line, 512);

    if (n < 0) {
      printf("\nError in read"); 
      exit(0);
    } else if (n == 0) {
      return;
    } 
    line[n-1] = NULL;
    printf("Yo baby got it:%d\n",n);
    //printf("%s\n",line);
    //printf("####################################\n");


    //split it and store it variables
    rc = split( line, ':', &res, &count );
    if( rc ) {
    printf("Error: error in spliting \n");
    }

    *ptr_ip_addr = res[0];
    *ptr_port_no = res[1];
    *ptr_page = res[2];
    printf("in getClientInput ->%s \n",*ptr_ip_addr);
    printf("in getClientInput ->%s \n",*ptr_port_no);
    printf("in getClientInput ->%s \n",*ptr_page);
    //close(sockfd);                    //closed here earlier
}

int split( char * str, char delim, char ***array, int *length ) {
  char *p;
  char **res;
  int count=0;
  int k=0;
  int index = 0;

  do{
    //printf("%c\n", str[]);
    index++;
  } while (str[index] != NULL);
  str[index] = ':';
  index++;
  str[index] = NULL;

  printf("%s--------------------------\n",str);

  p = str;
  // Count occurance of delim in string
  while( (p=strchr(p,delim)) != NULL ) {
    *p = 0; // Null terminate the deliminator.
    p++; // Skip past our new null
    count++;
  }

  // allocate dynamic array
  res = calloc( 1, count * sizeof(char *));
  if( !res ) return -1;

  p = str;
  for( k=0; k<count; k++ ){
    if( *p ) res[k] = p;  // Copy start of string
    p = strchr(p, 0 );    // Look for next null
    p++; // Start of next string
  }

  *array = res;
  *length = count;

  return 0;
}

int connect_web(char * ip_addr_old, char * port_old, char * page_old) {

  struct addrinfo hints, *res;
  int sockfd, retVal;
  char * ip_addr="www.website.edu";
  char * port ="80";

  printf("11111..ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> %s \n port in connect_web 2-> %s \n page in connect_web 3->%s\n",ip_addr_old,port_old,page_old);


  printf("ip_addr in connect_web -> %s \n port in connect_web-> %s \n",ip_addr,port);
  printf("size= %d\n",strlen(ip_addr));

  // first, load up address structs with getaddrinfo():
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  printf("2222222.ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> %s \n port in connect_web 2-> %s \n page in connect_web 3->%s\n",ip_addr_old,port_old,page_old);

  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  retVal=getaddrinfo(ip_addr, port, &hints, &res);
  printf("getaddrinfo Return Val is -> %d\n",retVal);
  // create a socket:
  printf("33333333.ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> %s \n port in connect_web 2-> %s \n page in connect_web 3->%s\n",ip_addr_old,port_old,page_old);

  sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    /* connecting to the server */
    //connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
  printf("444444.ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> %s \n port in connect_web 2-> %s \n page in connect_web 3->%s\n",ip_addr_old,port_old,page_old);

  if (connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    printf("\n: Error in connect to web page");
    exit(0);
  }
  printf("55555.ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> %s \n port in connect_web 2-> %s \n page in connect_web 3->%s\n",ip_addr_old,port_old,page_old);

  return sockfd;

}
void process_webPage(int soc_client, int soc_web, char * page, char * host){
  char arr[200];
  char * sendline; 
  char recvline[4096];
  int n,rv;
  struct pollfd ufds[2];

  printf("\n%s----------in process_webPage\n",page);
  printf("\n%s----------in process_webPage\n",host);

  //ufds[0].fd = s1;
  //ufds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI; // check for normal or out-of-band

  ufds[1].fd = soc_web;
  ufds[1].events = POLLIN; // check for just normal data

  // Prepare the HTTP request
  sendline = arr;
  strcpy(arr,"GET ");
  strcat(arr,page);
  strcat(arr," HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:");
  strcat(arr,host);
  strcat(arr,"\r\n\r\n");


  /* send it to server */
  printf ("%s\n",sendline);
  if (write(soc_web, (const void*) sendline, strlen(sendline)) < 0) {
    printf("\n: Error in write to web server socket");
    exit(0);
  }


  // Receive data from Socket
  rv = poll(ufds, 2, 3500);
  /*while ( rv > 0) {
    if (rv == -1) {
      perror("poll"); // error occurred in poll()
    } else if (rv == 0) {
      printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 3.5 seconds.\n");
    } else {
      if (ufds[1].revents & POLLIN) {
        recv(soc_web, recvline, 4096-1, 0);
      }
    } 
    //fputs(recvline, stdout);
    printf("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm %d", rv);
    rv = poll(ufds, 2, 3500);
  }*/
  printf("@@@@@@@@@@@@ Out Side @@@@@@@@@@@\n");

  close(soc_web);
}
```

Here is the out put

```
Yo baby got it:37
www.website.edu:80:/~page/index.html:--------------------------
in getClientInput ->www.website.edu 
in getClientInput ->80 
in getClientInput ->/~page/index.html 
ip_addr in process_request_client -> www.website.edu 
 port in process_request_client-> 80 
 page in process_request_client->/~page/index.html
11111..ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> www.website.edu 
 port in connect_web 2-> 80 
 page in connect_web 3->/~page/index.html
ip_addr in connect_web -> www.utdallas.edu 
 port in connect_web-> 80 
size= 16
2222222.ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> �q�website.edu 
 port in connect_web 2-> 80 
 page in connect_web 3->/
getaddrinfo Return Val is -> 0
33333333.ip_addr in connect_web 1 ->  
 port in connect_web 2->  
 page in connect_web 3->
444444.ip_addr in connect_web 1 ->  
 port in connect_web 2->  
 page in connect_web 3->
55555.ip_addr in connect_web 1 -> �q�webs�PS�`PS� 
 port in connect_web 2->  
 page in connect_web 3->
ip_addr in process_request_client -> �q�webs�PS�`PS� 
 port in process_request_client->  
 page in process_request_client->
ip_addr in process_request_client -> �q�webs�PS�`PS� 
 port in process_request_client->  
 page in process_request_client->
```

Comment: Can u paste the prints?

Comment: Why do you use `memset` and afterwards setting some members of `hints` manually, instead of directly using a struct-initializer and letting the compiler do it all at once? Would be shorter and much more readable...

Comment: Aside: Keep your line-length reasonable. You really don't need lines longer than 80 characters! Horizontal scrolling is deadly.

Comment: What are the three passed-in pointers pointing to?  Are they pointing to data that is guaranteed to remain valid for the lifetime of the process_request_client thread?  Or are they pointing to data that gets freed or overwritten in the main thread, in parallel with the process_request_client thread?  If the latter, that could be your problem.

Comment: What if you run in a debugger, put a break at your function, and trace its execution step by step?

Comment: I don't repro the problem with a simple wrapper for calling `connect_web()`.  I suspect that @JeremyFriesner is correct that the strings you're passing to `connect_web()` are no longer valid and just happen to point to stale data that looks OK before the `memset()` call and is wiped out by the time the `printf("2222222...")` gets around to being executed.  If that doesn't help you, post a small, complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBurr here goes my code...

Comment: @JermeyFriesner As pointers are not in the main I guess there is no chances of getting modified by threads....am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your pointers `ip_addr`, `port_no`, `page` are all pointing into `char line[512];` which is a local variable to the `getClientInput` function. After this function returns that memory is deallocated.

Your symptoms in `connect_web` occur because that memory is reused for local variables inside `connect_web`; so modifying those local variables means that the contents of `char line[512]`, which your pointers point to, appears to change.

To fix this you could make that be `static char line[512];`, or you could have the `getClientInput` function dynamically allocate memory for each of the strings it is "returning".

However your code is already pretty messy and hard to follow, it's not surprising that you have memory errors. I would recommend to make a `struct` containing all of the pointers you need (instead of having an *ad hoc* array of 3 pointers, or a list of function parameters), and make sure you allocate everything for an instance of that struct in one place. Then you can have a single function to free an entire struct once you're doine with it.

Comment: Also, `getClientInput` should check `count >= 3` before accessing `res[0]`, `res[1]`, `res[2]`

Comment: thanks @MattMcNabb for figuring out the issue ... I removed all the pointers and pointers to pointers. Instead I used a structure inside process_request_client() and passed it to the required functions.